# Clarification about if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Got that code:

```js
function orderMyLogic(val) {
  if (val < 10) {
    return "Less than 10";
  } else if (val < 5) {
    return "Less than 5";
  } else {
    return "Greater than or equal to 10";
  }
}


console.log(orderMyLogic(7));
console.log(orderMyLogic(4));
console.log(orderMyLogic(11));
```

So the result is

```
Less than 10
Less than 10
Greater than or equal to 10
```

I understand why this is the result, but what options in syntax ( if there is )
that i can take so their outcome will be the same as in the code below
without changing the places of ( val < 10 ) and ( val < 5 )

```js
function orderMyLogic(val) {
  if (val < 5) {
    return "Less than 5";
  } else if (val < 10) {
    return "Less than 10";
  } else {
    return "Greater than or equal to 10";
  }
}

console.log(orderMyLogic(7));
console.log(orderMyLogic(4));
console.log(orderMyLogic(11));
```

that the result will be:

```
Less than 10
Less than 5
Greater than or equal to 10
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: `if(val < 10 && >= 5)`

Comment: If there is another option instead of "if" that i can write so its will see that its also suits the statment "less than 5 "

Comment: There is no conditional statement in javascript that will ignore the order of execution. Since less then 5 is always less then 10, to keep this order, you'll have to change the first condition so it will be `false` when `val` is less or equal to 5.

Comment: Any number less than 5 is also less than 10. So if you want 3 to output "less than 5" and not "less than 10" then you must order the conditional tests for the desired behavior:  < 5, < 10, < 20 etc. This is not a question of syntax but algorithm logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a solution without an `if` statement, you could use the [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) with the values.

```js
function orderMyLogic(val) {
    return val < 5
        ? "Less than 5"
        : val < 10
            ? "Less than 10"
            : "Greater than or equal to 10";
}

console.log(orderMyLogic(7));
console.log(orderMyLogic(4));
console.log(orderMyLogic(11));
```